# Confirm password message appears before entering value in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written following code in aspx page in asp.net c# application

```
<section>
      <label>
         <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password *"></asp:Label></label>
      <label class="input">

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" data-content="Please Enter Your Password?" data-rel="popover" data-original-title="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="state-error" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ControlToValidate="txtPassword">please enter password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </label>
        </section>

        <section>
            <label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password *"></asp:Label></label>
            <label class="input">

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfrimPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" data-content="Please Confirm Your Password?" data-rel="popover" data-original-title="Confrim Password"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true"
                    CssClass="state-error" ControlToValidate="txtConfrimPassword">Please re-enter your password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="valComPassword" CssClass="state-error" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ControlToCompare="txtConfrimPassword"
                    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Confirm password does not match"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </label>
        </section>
```

Now the issue is when user type their password in `txtPassword` textbox, the validation (confirm password) appears beneath the `txtConfirmPassword` textbox. I want that it should appear after user will enter their wrong password in `txtConfirm` textbox.

Comment: I've noticed that many sites validate on text change, so when you start typing in confirm it says invalid until it matches... I don't see it as a problem.

Comment: Why do you have nested labels ?!?!?! <label><asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password *"></asp:Label></label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the property `ControlToCompare` to `txtConfrimPassword` and start typing in `txtPassword` textbox this validation fails since when you type in `txtPassword` textbox the confirm password textbox is empty.

So you can simply validate the password textbox instead of confirm textbox.

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="valComPassword"  CssClass="state-error"  
    ControlToValidate="txtConfrimPassword" ControlToCompare="txtPassword" 
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true" 
    ErrorMessage="Confirm password does not match">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

This will not throw the error message untill you start typing in `txtConfrimPassword` textbox which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just tidying up your code, try this:

```
<section>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password *"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" data-content="Please Enter Your Password?" data-rel="popover" data-original-title="Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="state-error" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtPassword">please enter password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</section>

<section>
    <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password *"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfrimPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" data-content="Please Confirm Your Password?" data-rel="popover" data-original-title="Confrim Password"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="state-error" ControlToValidate="txtConfrimPassword">Please re-enter your password</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="valComPassword" CssClass="state-error" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ControlToCompare="txtConfrimPassword" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="profile" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Confirm password does not match"></asp:CompareValidator>
</section>
```